# Use related entity's IQueryable in IQueryable of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I am using EF Core and Linq.

Assume I have a class called Dog. The Dog table has an has-a relationship to the Mammal table. 
Consider the following files for searching and querying the database:

```
public class DogSearch
{
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public int? NumberOfLegs{get;set;}
      public string Breed{get;set}

     IQueryable<Dog> BuildSearchQuery(IQueryable<Dog> qry)
    {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            qry = qry.Where(a => a.Mammal.Name.Contains(Name));

      if (NumberOfLegs != null)
            qry = qry.Where(a => a.Mammal.NumberOfLegs == NumberOfLegs);

      if (Breed != null))
            qry = qry.Where(a => a.Breed== Breed);

      return qry;

    }
}



public class MammalSearch
{
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public int? NumberOfLegs{get;set;}

     IQueryable<Mammal> BuildSearchQuery(IQueryable<Mammal> qry)
    {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            qry = qry.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(Name));

      if (NumberOfLegs != null)
            qry = qry.Where(a => a.NumberOfLegs == NumberOfLegs);

       return qry;

    }
}
```

I would like to share the code in the MammalSearch class with the DogSearch class somehow. This is so that the searches on Name and NumberOfLegs can be maintained in one place. I am struggling to refactor it to do that. How can I allow the `IQueryable<Dog>` to make use of the `IQueryable<Mammal>` ?

Edit:

The POCOs being used by EF are as follows:

```
public class Dog
{
   public Id{get;set;}
   public string Breed{get;set}
   public Guid MammalId{get;set;}
   [ForeignKey(nameof(MammalId))]
   public Mammal Mammal{get;set;}
 }

public class Mammal
{
   public Id {get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set}
   public int NumberOfLegs{get;set;}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the relation between dog and mamal as a 'has-a' relationship (It would be an 'is-a' relationship if used inheritance), I would proceed as the following:

Create a property named Dogs of type `ICollection<Dog>` inside the Mammal class:

```
public class Mammal
{ 
    ...
    public ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}
```

Change your `DogSearch.BuildSearchQuery()` to receive an `IQueryable<Mammal>` instead, like so:

```
public IQueryable<Dog> BuildSearchQuery(IQueryable<Mammal> qry)
{
    var mamals = new MammalSearch().BuildSearchQuery(qry); //Use injection or something else to create the MammalSearch class

    var dogs = mamals.SelectMany(a => a.Dogs);

    if (Breed != null)
        dogs = dogs.Where(a => a.Breed == Breed);

    return dogs;
}
```

This will cause the mammal and dog classes to be joined and filtered by the EF.

Comment: This makes sense. I have corrected my question to say "has-a" rather than "is-a"